# question about K-fold cross validation in classification tree model in big data

Tags: r, cross-validation

I want perform a 5-fold CV for a classification tree model with packages"rpart", before this i use a code to divide my data into 5 subdatasets, and 1 error comes out:
  errors come out during the data-dividing step, like:

*Error in `*tmp*`[] : subscript out of bounds*

I has google the error, but still can't solve it .

my data is a little big, more than 370,000 rows and 13 predicted variables.
  And there are 51 levels in my response variable.

```
> w <- read.csv('D:/R code/animal2.csv',header = T)
> names(w)
[1] "cluster_ward50" "AAT10"          "AAT0"           "ARIDITY"        "VEGETATION"    
[6] "PRECITAT"       "TMAX"           "TMIN"           "PREMAX"         "PREMIN"        
[11] "AMT"            "T_OC"           "ELEMAX"         "ELEMIN"        
> 
> w$cluster_ward50 <- as.factor(w$cluster_ward50)
> w$VEGETATION <- as.factor(w$VEGETATION)
> d <- 1:370827
> dd <- list()
> Z <- 5
> nn <- levels(w$cluster_ward50)
    > KL <- length(nn)
    > for(i in 1:KL)
    +   dd[[i]] <- d[w$cluster_ward50==nn]
> kk<- NULL
> for(i in 1:KL)
+   kk <- c(kk,round(length(dd[[i]])/Z))
> set.seed(1111)
> yy <- list(NULL,NULL,NULL)
> for(i in 1:KL){xx <- list()
+                uu<-dd[[i]]
+                for(j in 1:(Z-1)){xx[[j]] <- sample(uu,kk)
+                                  uu<- setdiff(uu,xx[[j]])}
+                xx[[Z]] <- uu
+                for(k in 1:Z)
+                  yy[[i]][[k]] <- xx[[k]]}
Error in `*tmp*`[] : subscript out of bounds
> mm <- list(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
> for(i in 1:Z)
+   for(j in 1:KL)
+     mm[[i]] <- c(mm[[i]],yy[[j]][])
Error in yy[[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Hi Archer! Welcome to cross validated :-) Your question is about programming rather than about statistics. I'll therefore vote to move it to either the code review or  the stackexchange sister site where it is more on topic.

Comment: Thank you, I think it would be better for me

Comment: It is great that you provide code. But as your example code is right now, it is really difficult for us to follow it. Please tidy it up so we can easily read it and moreover, so that we can execute it by copy and paste into R: it needs to be self-contained (i.e. set up a dummy data.frame, and formulate the problem with that one, or use e.g. `iris`). Also, please use meaningful variable names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding programming errors or problems with software.

Answer (score 0):

- The meaning of your error message is that you request somehow an index that does not exist.
  You can check the current state of your looping variable after the error occurs. This means that you can inspect the calculation that went wrong "post-mortem".
- R has packages that do the tedious work of cross validation for you, e.g. [cvTools](http://cran.r-project.org/package=cvTools)
  cvTools allows you to provide functions that do the modeling and calculate the loss/performance measure. You need to have an appropriate `predict` method as well (particularly, I believe it needs to return the predicted quantity in the first element of the result structure, but I'm not sure about this). You'd have to use your own classification performance measure if you want any of those.

Please read some of the many posts on this site on model comparison: to do it in a statistically sound way, you need extremely large test sets.

Comment: Thank cbeleites, actually I just want to use the data-dividing code to perform CV for model comparison with rpart, adabag, bagging, randomforest and so on. And I don't have much knowledge about the cvTools, does the package can perform CV for all of these methods i want to try. Besides, I just find the cv code(including data-dividing) from a book, I'm newly to R.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading the manuals of the CVTools, and I want to ask a question: the CVTools is a cv tool for regression models, can it perform CV for the classification models? And may I use the CVTools after running a classification model?

Comment: You need to supply an appropriate cost function. CV itself doesn't differ between regression and classification models. Wrt. whether you can use cvTools after fitting your model: from a programming point of view, no problem. From a statistics point of view, it all depends on what you want to measure and how you interprete the CV results. I suggest that you read about the general ideas and dos and don'ts e.g. on cross validated and in the literature.